# How to conditionally require a field based on a selection in a form?

Tags: forms, plone, z3c.form

I am using Plone and z3c.forms. There is a field at the top that selects what content object we are creating. It then shows the fields needed to build that object.

I need to be able to conditionally require fields based on what content object is selected at the top of the form. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible; what you need is called an "invariant validator".
Have a look [here](http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/schema-driven-forms/customising-form-behaviour/validation.html#invariants).

Comment: I might add that it will improve your form usability to enforce this on both the client and server side. The invariant validator does the server-side work. You may use simple javascript code to enforce it on the client side by catching the change event on the first field.

Comment: To avoid link only answers, you should add a small example, how it works. Also some JS hints for the client part would be nice.